# Editable Sitecore fields with Glass

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper, razor

Folks

I'm trying to do something basic here which is have a general link and an image field as editable in experience editor on my view using Glass. 
my end goal is to have two editable fields which are rendered as:

```html
<a><img></img><a>
```

I am trying to do something like this but this is not working well

```razor
@Html.Glass().Editable(Model, m => m.MyLinkField, new { img = Model.MyImageField })
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```razor
@using (Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(Model, m => m.MyLinkField, null, true) {
  @Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, m => m.MyImageField, null, true)
}
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. thanks Corey!

Comment: if your view is inheriting from glassView then you can do this:@using (BeginRenderLink(Model, x => x.Link, isEditable: true))
 {
     @RenderImage(Model, x => x.Image, isEditable: true)
 }